A problem on right-ordered groups.
In a paper Small doubling in ordered groups:
generators and structure it is proven in Lemma 3 page no. 595 that:
Let $G$ be an ordered group. Let $T$ be a non-empty finite subset of $G$
and let $t$ denote its maximal element max $T$ . Let $x \in G$ be an element satisfying
$x > t$. If $yx; xy \in T^2$ ( $T^2=\{t_1t_2\mid t_1, t_2\in T\}$) for each $y \in T\setminus\{t\}$, then  $T\subseteq\langle t, x\rangle.$
I am interested in looking at this in terms of a right-ordered group.
Let $T$ be a non-empty finite subset of a right-ordered group $G$ and let $ t$ denote its maximal element max $T$. Let $x \in G$ be an element satisfying $x > t.$ If $ yx, xy \in T^2$ for each $y\in T\setminus\{t\}$, can we say $T\subseteq\langle t, x\rangle?$ Or what can we say about the structure of $T$?
I tried to prove in this way
Write $|T|=k$ and  $$T=\{t_k, t_{k-1},\ldots, t_1\}  \text{  where  } t_k<t_{k-1}<\cdots<t_1=t.$$
We prove by induction that for any $j$ such that $1\leq j\leq k$, we have $t_j \in \langle t, x\rangle$, where $|T|=k$.
For the base case $j = 1$, we have $t_1=t\in \langle t, x\rangle$.
For the inductive step, assume that we have proved that $t_1, \ldots, t_j\in \langle t, x\rangle$, for some $j$ satisfying $1\leq j\leq k-1$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $xt_{j+1}\leq t_{j+1}x$.
By assumption, we have $t_{j+1}x, xt_{j+1}\in T^2$. It follows that $t_{j+1}x=t_ut_v$ for some $t_u, t_v \in T$. But $x > t \geq t_u, t_v$ and $t_{j+1}x=t_ut_v\geq xt_{j+1}>t_{j+1}^2$.
Now if we have $t_u, t_v > t_{j+1}$, which gives us $u, v \leq j$. The induction hypothesis implies $t_u, t_v \in \langle t, x\rangle$. Consequently, $t_{j+1}=x^{-1}t_ut_v\in \langle t, x\rangle$, and the inductive step is completed. Hence, $T
\subseteq \langle t, x\rangle$, as required.
But what if $t_u,t_v\leq t_{j+1}.$ Can we have $t_{j+1}^2<xt_{j+1}\leq t_{j+1}x=t_ut_v<x^2$?
I think this is not correct because by right ordered groups by P conrad, if $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is a finite subset of $G$(right-ordered group) that does not contain $e,$ then there exist $e_i=\pm1$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$ such that $e$ does not belong to the subsemigroup of $G$ that is generated by $\{x_1^{e_1},\ldots, x_n^{e_n}\}.$ So by using this, we can say that $T\not\subseteq\langle t, x \rangle. $ (since $e\in T.$)
But what can we say about the structure of $T$, if $yx; xy \in T^2$  for each $y \in T\setminus\{t\}$? I tried with some examples, but it was coming Abelian set.
I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Problem: Let $T$ be a non-empty finite subset of positive elements of a right-ordered group $G$ and let $ t$ denote its maximal element max $T$. Let $x \in G$ be an element satisfying $x > t.$ If $ yx, xy \in T^2$ for each $y\in T\setminus\{t\}$, can we say $T\subseteq\langle t, x\rangle?$
I tried to prove in this way
Write $|T|=k$ and  $$T=\{t_k, t_{k-1},\ldots, t_1\}  \text{  where  } t_k<t_{k-1}<\cdots<t_1=t.$$
We prove by induction that for any $j$ such that $1\leq j\leq k$, we have $t_j \in \langle t, x\rangle$, where $|T|=k$.
For the base case $j = 1$, we have $t_1=t\in \langle t, x\rangle$.
For the inductive step,
Assume that for any subset $S\subseteq T$ with $|S|=k-1$ , we have $S\in \langle t,x\rangle.$
By assumption, we have $t_kx, xt_k\in T^2$. It follows that $t_kx=t_ut_v$ for some $t_u, t_v \in T$. But $x > t \geq t_u, t_v>t_k$ , which gives us $u, v \leq j$. The induction hypothesis implies $t_u, t_v \in \langle t, x\rangle$. Consequently, $t_{j+1}=x^{-1}t_ut_v\in \langle t, x\rangle$, and the inductive step is completed. Hence, $T
\subseteq \langle t, x\rangle$, as required.
Is this proof correct?
